# Implementations of Ntru TLS

Tags: key-exchange, post-quantum-cryptography, ntru

Has anyone come across any implementations of Ntru TLS? I'm working a project for uni that does quantum secure encryption. It relies on a mix of Ntru & AES, but I can't find an implementation of Ntru TLS anywhere. (CyaSSL claims to have one but it needs a license to compile, I've contacted them, waiting to hear back)

Specifically, the following ciphers:

```
TLS_NTRU_NSS_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_NTRU_NSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_NTRU_NSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_NTRU_NSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_NTRU_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_NTRU_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_NTRU_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_NTRU_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
```

Or – even better – has anyone encountered any type of SSL/TLS implementation that doesn't rely of the discrete logarithm problem, factoring prime numbers, or elliptic curves? I've scoured the internet and come up with nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The open source version of CyaSSL contains code that calls into the commercial NTRU library -- the library itself is missing of course. You might be able to make CyaSSL work with the open source NTRU implementation at https://github.com/tbuktu/libntru ; it's alpha level software though.

Comment: Hey Tim, Security Innovations got back to me and provided a student / not for profit license to use it. It's in C so there will be some hackery required, but it will work hopefully.

Comment: BTW, NTRU is now available under the GPL and other FOSS licenses: https://github.com/NTRUOpenSourceProject/ntru-crypto. The open-source version has not yet been fully integrated into CyaSSL though.